# NotePad++ RegEx Duplicate text inside tags. How?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have searched and tried much and eventually cannot understand how to do it.

I have a very long list of this:

```
    <datalist>
<option value="1">Moscow, The Great Russia</option>
<option value="2">Saint-Petersburg, The Great Russia</option>
<option value="3">Novosibirsk, The Great Russia</option>
<option value="4">Ekaterinburg, The Great Russia</option>
<option value="5">Kazan, The Great Russia</option>
</datalist>
```

I want it to be this way:

```
    <datalist>
<option value="Moscow, The Great Russia">Moscow, The Great Russia</option>
<option value="Saint-Petersburg, The Great Russia">Saint-Petersburg, The Great Russia</option>
<option value="Novosibirsk, The Great Russia">Novosibirsk, The Great Russia</option>
<option value="Ekaterinburg, The Great Russia">Ekaterinburg, The Great Russia</option>
<option value="Kazan, The Great Russia">Kazan, The Great Russia</option>
</datalist>
```

How to do this in NotePad++ using Regular Expressions?

Answer (score 1):

Search:

```
"[^"]*">(.*?)(?=<\/)
```

replace with:

```
"\1">\1
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/mQ3dB2/2)

Answer (score 0):

Find what: `\d.+>(.*)<`
Replace with: `$1">$1<`

Comment: You'll have big problem if there are more than one `<option` tag in the same line!

Comment: Didn't understand you sir? Was there anything wrong in my answer, I checked it again but notice no error...

Comment: Just try it with `<option value="1">Moscow, The Great Russia</option><option value="2">Saint-Petersburg, The Great Russia</option>` (no linebreak between)